# CRUD update using PUT

Tags: java, crud, hsqldb

I am attempting to update variables inside a table of a HSQLDB. When calling the following update, it doesn't seem to go any further than this line of code:

```
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Here is the full update code:

TeamClient.java

```
    public static void update(String id, String id1, String player1, String player2, String player3, String player4, String player5, String name) throws Exception
{
    URI uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("http")
            .setHost("localhost")
            .setPort(8080)
            .setPath("/A00196363DonnachaOhA/rest/teams")
            .build();
    System.out.println(uri.toString());
    HttpPut httpPost = new HttpPut(uri);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html");

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id1", id1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("player1", player1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("player2", player2));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("player3", player3));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("player4", player4));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("player5", player5));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));

    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)) ;
    System.out.println("Sending request");
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

}
```

TeamDAO.java

```
    public void update(int id, int id2, String player1, String player2, String player3, String player4, String player5, String name) {
  Connection connection = getConnection();
  System.out.println("TRYING");  
  try
  {
      System.out.println("TRYING");
      PreparedStatement psmt = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE TEAMS SET id=?, player1=?, player2=?, player3=?, player4=?, player5=?, name=? WHERE id =?");
      psmt.setInt(1, id);
      psmt.setInt(8, id2);
      psmt.setString(2, player1);
      psmt.setString(3, player2);
      psmt.setString(4, player3);
      psmt.setString(5, player4);
      psmt.setString(6, player5);
      psmt.setString(7, name);
      int rs = psmt.executeUpdate(); 
  }catch (SQLException e) 
  {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}
}

TeamResource.java

```
    @PUT
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("{teamId}")
public void putTeam(@FormParam("id") int id,
        @FormParam("id2") int id2,
        @FormParam("name") String name, 
        @FormParam("player1") String player1,
        @FormParam("player2") String player2, 
        @FormParam("player3") String player3, 
        @FormParam("player4") String player4, 
        @FormParam("player5") String player5,
        @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("PUT id = " + id);
    TeamDAO.instance.update(id, id2, name, player1, player2, player3, player4, player5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have implemented the `put` method with two form parameters with the same name.

```
public void putTeam(@FormParam("id") int id,
        @FormParam("id") int id2,
```

Next problem:

```
UPDATE TEAMS SET id=?, player1=?, player2=?, player3=?, 
                 player4=?, player5=?, name=? WHERE id =?
```

If the first `id` and second `id` are supposed to be the same, then you should be doing this

```
psmt.setInt(1, id);
psmt.setInt(8, id);
```

and getting rid of `id2`.  On the other hand if they are supposed to be different, then the form parameter bug (see above) breaks the query ... because it will cause one of the parameters to be ignored.

Then there is this:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id1", id1));
```

So is the name of the second parameter supposed to be "id1" ... or "id2"?

Finally, I have my doubts that this update is *sound* from a semantic perspective.  If the `id` field is a primary key that is a foreign key in some other table, then your update will be breaking the foreign key-based association with other rows.  At the very least, this looks "odd".

Comment: Didn't spot that, thank you. I have a feeling however it has to do with the teamClient update.

Comment: The two ids are meant to be different, I have changed all the second id variables to 'id1'. My code looks very odd because I'm still learning and trying my best to create programs.

Comment: It is not that it looks odd.  I am trying to point out that it is doing something that is semantically odd.  What are you trying to achieve by changing the "id" of the row?